# ExcelJS and formatting text

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I'm trying to format a value in ExcelJS.
I am targeting getCell('A1') and the value should be: vehicle: CP0555LP-JHB(A)
I need only the **vehicle:** to be bold and the rest of the text plain.
Is this doable in the same cell?

So just to recap, I need it to be like this **vehicle:** CP0555LP-JHB(A) but just using cell('A1'). I tried several approaches but I am not sure one could do this without using for instance vehicle: in cell('A1') and then the rest of the text in cell('B1'). Problem is I have set my columns widths so the last part of the text will be seperated to far.

```
  sheet.getCell('A1').value = {
  richText: [
    {
      text: 'Vehicle: CP0555LP-JHB(A)',
      font: { bold: true },
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.